# ExpandableListView getChildView() on collapsing

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a fragment that is inflating an `ExpandableListView`. It is programmed to animate the children views to come in from the right of the screen each time the group view is expanded. That part works great.

Here's the problem:

In that same fragment I have created an `OnGroupClickListener` where I check to see if it is expanding or collapsing. Upon collapse, I want to access the children views to animate them out. How can I access those child views? The adapter doesn't call `getChildView()` on collapsing..., only `getGroupView()`.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Kent, did you find the solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: Nope. I reworked the whole thing to be a custom view where i could drag one of the listItem views to show a view behind it.

Comment: I have also same problem can u please update me about this